# $F/K$ with a rational place $\Rightarrow F=K(x,y)$ with $[F:K(x)]=[F:K(y)]=2g+1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, function-fields

> Let $F/K$ be a function field in one variable with genus $g$. If there is a place $P$ with degree  one, then $\exists\,x,y\in F$ such that $F=K(x,y)$ and $[F:K(x)]=[F:K(y)]=2g+1$.

I'm really lost in this problem.

My first idea was to consider the case $g=1$. That would be an elliptic curve, which may be considered in the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ (I don't know how to prove this; I've read this is true, so I'll use it to look for ideas).

Defining $x'=x-y$, we have $y^2=(x'+y)^3+a(x'+y)+b$. Then
$$[K(x',y):K(x')]=[K(x',y):K(y)]=3=2\cdot 1+1,$$

and we are done, but I still don't know what to do with the general case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know $\ell(nP)$ for a few $n$ and a way to ensure $L(nP)$ generates the function field

Comment: @reuns, I've just read a proof that $g=1\Rightarrow y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and I'm trying to use some of the ideas, which involve the spaces $L(nP)$. For simplicity, I'm trying to work out $g=2$. In that case, $\ell(nP)=n-1$ for $n\geq 3$. So $L(3P)=\langle 1,x\rangle$ for some $x$. My first question is: what should $v_P(x)$ be? In principle, it could be $-1,-2$ or -3$, right? How do I decide it?

Comment: (this question didn't arise in the simpler case $g=1$, but I think it will for $g\geq 2$)

Comment: Say $K = \overline{K}$. $\ell(0P)=1$, if $\ell(P)=1,L(P)= K+Kh$ then $F = K(h)$ (look at $div(\frac{h-h(Q_1)}{h-h(Q_2)})$ to transform any function into a function with no poles). What is $\ell(2P)$ ? If it is $2$ then show (group law on the Picard group or Riemann Roch ?) it is an elliptic curve. Thus for $g=2$ we have $\ell(2P)=1$ and $\ell(3P)=2 \implies L(3P) =  K+Kx$ where $div(x)= Q_1+Q_2+Q_3-3P$. Also in function fields and codes I think they define the genus from $\ell(nP)$.

Comment: @reuns Ok. Now if I keep going, I'll have: $L(3P)=\langle 1,x\rangle, L(4P)=\langle 1,x, y\rangle$ (with $v_P(y)=-4$), $L(5P)=\langle 1,x, y, z\rangle$ (with $v_P(z)=-5$), ..., $L(8P)=\langle 1,x,y,z, x^2, xy,y^2\rangle$ and I conclude $\{1,x,y,z,x^2,xy,y^2, xz\}$ are linearly dependent. How do I deal with $z$ and how will $2g+1=2\cdot 2+1=5$ show up?

Comment: @reuns, I still can't see how to deal with the general case. Any other suggestion? I've been thinking a lot about this problem, but I'm runnning in circles.

Comment: I'm lost even for $g=2$. I suppose that since $[F:K(z)]=5$, we should pick $z$ and $z-y$, but I can't prove that $F=K(z,z-y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much thinking, I came up with a much simpler solution than I expected.

If $g=0$, then $F=K(t)$ for some $t\in F$, since there is a rational place. So we just need $x=y=t$.

If $g>0$, take $s,t\in F$ such that $(s)_\infty=2gP$ and $(t)_\infty=(2g+1)P$ (this is possible because $2g,2g+1\geq 2g$). This way $[F:k(s)]=\deg(s)_\infty =2g$ and $[F:K(t)]=\deg(t)_\infty =2g+1$. Examining the degrees of the subextensions, $[F:K(s,t)]$ must divide both $2g$ and $2g+1$, which are coprime, so $[F:K(s,t)]=1\Rightarrow F=K(s,t)$.

Taking $x:=t$ and $y:=t+s$, we clearly have $F=K(x,y)$ and $(x)_\infty=(y)_\infty=(2g+1)P$, so $[F:K(x)]=[F:K(y)]=2g+1$.